# pageshow vs pageinit, why does my page load successfully using pageshow but not pageinit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am working on a webworks app for blackberry 7 and I have run into an interesting dillema. The code I have runs perfectly in a normal browser (Chrome) but not the device browser.

I have a webservice call that needs to be called on pageinit. The strange thing is this. The call and everything works perfectly on pageshow, but not on pageinit. If I execute the service on pageinit, the webservice call, (Get Policies) gets executed successfully and then it never continues with the rest of the code in the pageinit.

```
$('#ClaimsPage').bind('pageinit', function() {
    GetPolicies();
    //Never gets back to this point after completing the GetPolicies Function
    if (sessionStorage.wasSuccessful == 'true') {
        PolicyListBuilder(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.Policies));
    } else {
        goBack();
    }
            });
```

My webservice call is simple and is as follows.

```
function GetPolicies() {
    showBusy("Retrieving Policies...");
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Device", reportingDeviceId);
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", getAuth64());                
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: PolicyGetWsUrl(),
        success: function (resultMessage) {
            sessionStorage.wasSuccessful = resultMessage.WasSuccessful;
            if (resultMessage.WasSuccessful == true) {
                sessionStorage.Policies = JSON.stringify(resultMessage.PolicyList);
                hideBusy();
            } else {
                alert(resultMessage.Description);
            }
        },
        error: genErrorMessage
    });
    hideBusy();
}
```

The PolicyListBuilder function executes correctly, If I use

```
   $('#ClaimsPage').bind('pageshow', function()...
```

The program runs quite well, but I would rather have it on pageinit.  I also tried using .on () instead of .bind()

Is there perhaps something that I have missed ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

I should also note that I have used pageinit a few other places in the same application and they seem to work perfectly. It is quite strange. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: [what about mobileinit?](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)

Comment: mobileinit could work, but this is not the home page. if I use mobileinit it will mean I have to store data throughout the app that the user might never access. But thanks for your reply. I did not think of mobileinit. thats pretty clever :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason that the code will execute on pageshow and not pageinit ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have done some research and discovered a few things.

pageinit happens before the entire DOM has loaded, therefore if you reference to controls, it might not yet exist and thus fail.

There is a workaround. you can either use .delegate() or $(document).ready()... Both of them seems to work. I will keep this open in case someone has a better answer.